# Who are these yoginis?

Tags: avatars, devi

The yoginis are a group that consistsof 64 goddesses.

> Some The Sixty-four Yogini as depicted in the complete Hirapur shrine are:
>   •Bahurupa
>
> •Tara
>
> •*Narmada*
>
> •*Yamuna*
>
> •Shanti
>
> •*Varuni*
>
> •Kshemankari
>
> •*Aindri*
>
> •*Varahi*
>
> •Ranveera
>
> •Vanara-Mukhi
>
> •*Vaishnavi*
>
> •*Kalaratri*
>
> •Vaidyaroopa
>
> •Charchika
>
> •Betali
>
> •*Chinnamastika*
>
> •Vrishabahana
>
> •Jwala Kamini
>
> •Ghatavara
>
> •Karakali
>
> •*Saraswati*
>
> •Birupa
>
> •Kauveri
>
> •Bhaluka
>
> •*Narasimhi*
>
> •Biraja
>
> •Vikatanna
>
> •*Mahalakshmi*
>
> •*Kaumari*
>
> •*Maha Maya*
>
> •*Rati*
>
> •Karkari
>
> •Sarpashya
>
> •Yakshini
>
> •*Vinayaki*
>
> •Vindya Balini
>
> •Veera Kumari
>
> •*Maheshwari*
>
> •*Ambika*
>
> •Kamiyani
>
> •Ghatabari
>
> •Stutee
>
> •*Kali*
>
> •*Uma*
>
> •*Narayani*
>
> •Samudraa
>
> •*Brahmani*
>
> •*Jwala Mukhi*
>
> •*Agneyei*
>
> •*Aditi*
>
> •Chandrakanti
>
> •Vayubega
>
> •*Chamunda*
>
> •Murati
>
> •*Ganga*
>
> •*Dhumavati*
>
> •Gandhari
>
> •Sarva Mangala
>
> •Ajita
>
> •Surya Putri
>
> •Vayu Veena
>
> •Aghora
>
> •*Bhadrakali*

Link:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogini

Some of the Devis(the ones in italics) in this group are easily recognisable. But who are the rest of them?Do they have individual stories?

Note:I do not one stories of them collectively(e.g. I am not looking for a story about *all* the yoginis, instead, I am looking for a story about each and everyone of them)

Comment: IMO, The horizontal one looked good than vertical.

Comment: @Sree Charan I made it vertical coz some of the goddesses have two words for a name(e.g. Surya Putri) and I do not want people to mix up their names together(e.g. Surya Putri Vayu)

Comment: @Sree Charan In any case, do you anything about them?

Comment: No. I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These Yoginis are actually **Bhagavati's mates or sakhi or sahachari**. They are also called the **Avarana Devatas** . That is, they cover (or veil) the main Goddess, that is Bhagavati, in several layers ( avarana means layer).

Gods always like to be veiled and here these Yoginis provide that veil for Goddess Bhagavati. They also accompany serve Devi Bhagavati constantly. This  also shows that it is exceedingly difficult reaching the ultimate destination or Bhagavati. There are several thousand crores of such layers (or obstacles) to cross before reaching her.

The number or type of such Yoginis is actually more than crores. But the principle Yoginis are 64 in number as said by you.

They are together called the Chatuh Shashti Yoginis. The Brihannandikeswara Purana (an upapurana) lists the following 64 Yoginis :

> NArAyani, Gauri, ShAkambhari, BhimA, RaktadantikA, BhrAmari, PArvati,
>   DurgA, KatyAyini, MahAdevi, Chandraghanta, MahAvidyA, MahAtapA,
>   SAvitri, BrahmavAdini, BhadrakAli, VisAlakshi, RudrAni,
>   KrishnapingalA, AgnijwAlA, Raudramukhi, KAlarAtri, Tapaswini,
>   MeghaswanA, SahasrAkshi, VishnumayA, Jalodari, Mahodari, Muktakeshi,
>   GorarupA, MahAbala, Sruti, Smriti, Dhriti, Tushti, Pushti, MedhA,
>   VidyA, Lakshmi, Saraswati, AparnA, AmbikA, Yogini, DAkini, SAkini,
>   HArini, HAkini, LAkini, Tridaseswari, MahAshasti, Sarvamangala, LajjA,
>   Kaushiki, BrahmAni, MAheswari, KoumAri, Vaishnavi, Aindri, NArasimhi,
>   VarAhi, ChAmunda, Shivaduti, VishnumAyA and MAtrikA.

An explanation or nirukta of the word Yogini is given in KulArnava Tantram  as follows:

> **Yo**nimudrAnusandhAnAth **Gi**rijApAdasevanAth |
>   **Ni**rlinoPAdhivibhavAd YoginityAbhdhiyate ||
>
> ### Meaning
>
> She is known as Yogini, as she practices yonimudra, as she serves
>   the lotus feet of Girija (or Bhagavati) and also as she has
>   become devoid of upadhi.
>
> **KulArnava Tantra, Chapter 17, Verse 31.**

Upadhi here means the attributes. For example, richness is the upadhi for the rich. In Tantra,  Jiva's Jivatva is its upadhi. But it is ultimately the eternal Shiva which it does not know because of Avidya or ignorance. So, this upadhi is not eternal too. Once self knowledge is obtained the upadhi dissolves and the Jiva attains Shivatva.

The verse says that a Yogini's upadhi is also have been already dissolved. They know their true nature which is not different from Bhagavati Parameswari's. But they constantly serve her lotus feet too. And, Yonimudra is a secret mudra used in Devi's ritualistic Puja.

Also, that there are actually crores and crores of such avarana devatas or Yoginis is seen from the following verse which provides an explanation for the word Shakti:

> **Satakoti MaHadivyayogini** PritikAranAth | TivrasphurtipradAnnAncha Shaktityabhidhiyate ||
>
> ## Meaning
>
> She is known as Shakti, as she is the reason for bliss (or happiness,
>   actually priti is happiness) for the **hundred crores of great and
>   divine yoginis**, and as she gives intense energy.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram, Chapter 17, Verse 32.**

So, Yoginis are not exactly Devi's incarnations ( i am mentioning this  specifically since you added the avatara tag to your question) but her mates.

You must be knowing about Goddess Lalita  being constantly served by several devatas including Lakshmi, Saraswati etc. Goddess Lalita who resides along with Kameswara in the inner most triangle (in the bindu to be precise) of the Sri Chakra is  similarly being constantly served by crores and crores of other such Yogini-Devatas.

Comment: i had to do some reserch on these sixtyfour yoginis.One professor from Delhi had written a book on the topic also and there is Yoginis oracle. I read both but did not get the dhyanamantras.Neither did i find how lakshmi,sraswati,ganga, jamuna and other forms that are mentioned in different scriptures as devi are counted in yoginis in this tantra.could you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: the name of the books i read are Sixtyfour yoginis by prof Anamika Ray,  and the Yoginis' Oracle by OM publishers, BTW.

Comment: What do we mean by gods like to be veiled?

Comment: That means they don't really like to reveal their true nature easily. They like secrecy @Archit

Comment: then can they prevent us from worshipping them/ self realisation or mere Bhakti? Then they won’t even give us darshan?

Comment: I think it's mentioned in some Upanishad that deities love to hide their true identity. Does not mean that devotees won't get darshan of their favorite deities. They will if they do sufficient amount of hard work.@Archit

Answer (score 1):

Agni Purana, Chapter 52 mentions 64 Yoginis.

> 1. I shall describe (the characteristics) of the eight Yoginis (female attendants on Durgā) respectively residents of (the eight quarters) east to north-east. (The Yoginīs) Akṣobhyā, Rūkṣakarṇī, Rākṣasi, Kṛpaṇā and Akṣayā (reside in the east).

> 2. (The Yoginīs) Piṅgākṣī, Kṣayā, Kṣemā, Ilā, Līlā, Layā, Laktā, Balākeśī, Lālasā and Vimalā (dwell in the south-east).

> 3. (The Yoginīs) Hutāśā, Viśālākṣī, Huṅkārā, Vaḍavāmukhī, Mahākrūrā, Krodhanā, Bhayaṅkarī and Mahānanā (are the residents of the south).

> 4. (The Yoginīs) Sarvajñā, Taralā, Tārā, Ṛgvedā, Hayānanā, Sārā (Sārākhyā), Rudrasaṅgrāhī, Śambarā and Tālajaṅghikā (occupy the south (-west).

> 5. Raktākṣī, Suprasiddhā, Vidyujjihvā, Karaṅkiṇī, Meghanādā, Pracaṇḍogrā, Kālakarṇī and Varapradā (are the inmates of the west).

> 6. Candrā, Candrāvalī, Prapañcā, Pralayāntikā, Śiśuvaktrā, Piśācī, Piśitāśā and Lolupā (dwell in the north-west).

> 7. Dhamanī, Tāpanī, Rāgiṇī, Vikṛtānanā, Vāyuvegā, Bṛhatkukṣi, Vikṛtā and Viśvarūpikā (govern the north).

> 8. Yamajihvā, Jayanti, Durjayā, Jayantikā, Viḍālā, Revatī, Pūtanā and Vijayāntikā (hold sway over the north-east).

> 9. (These Yoginīs should be represented) as having eight arms (or) four arms, wielding weapons of their choice and yielding all benefits (on their votaries). (Lord) Bhairava may hold the arka plant (Calotropis gigantee) in the hand and have the face like the knee or elbow bearing the matted hair and the Moon.

Apart from this Purana, Kalika Purana also gives a list of 64 Yoginis (Chapter 63, verses 35-42).

Reference -

[The Agni Purana by N. Gangadharan](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083140.html)