# What is the story of the female goddess with an elephant head called Vinayaki?

Tags: goddess

I recently heard about the Goddess Vinayaki but my search over the internet [didn't give me a proper answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinayaki) about her. Who is she and what is her story according to scripture?

Note: It's not dupe of [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17102/who-are-these-yoginis) as it doesn't answer my question and is too broad too.